# How to do multiple selections on the datagrid before clicking on datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, startup, multi-select

I have WPF datagrid with multiple selections (the model has property IsSelected...) and it works fine, but when I start the program, I have to click on the table first, and after that, multiple selection works. When I first click on the table, it selects the item under the cursor (if I have pressed shift, it selects the item too, but it does not do multiple selections).

I supposed it can be because of datagrid is not focused, but when I do datagrid.Focus() on the loaded window, it doesn't work either. What should I do?

WPF DataGrid code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="3"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding CodebookUnitsUnitTable, Source={StaticResource Texts}}" Binding="{Binding Path=Unit}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding CodebookUnitsDescriptionTable, Source={StaticResource Texts}}" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" Width="5*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="SelectAll" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding CodebookContextMenuNewItem, Source={StaticResource Texts}}" Command="{Binding NewItemCommand}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <myComponents:AutoGreyableImage Height="20" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Width="20" Source="../Icons/Small/INovySM.gif" Stretch="None" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Key="Delete"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is set focused on the first row, not only on DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your Binding to `SelectedItem`, as this will set one selected item for the whole grid.

You can bind to the `IsSelected` property of each of your data Items (assuming you have an IsSelected property on your viewmodel for each item - MVVM) through styling:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
   </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: `SelectedItem` is not problem. Items has property IsSelected and I have styles in other resources. Multiple selection works fine, but when I `ShowDialog()`, I have to first click on table and only then I can select more than one item. If I show my dialog, press shift and click somewhere in table, it select only one item not more selection, after do this, multiple selection work fine.